# using sum() to find the aggregated price in a list of items

Tags: python, django

I have a list of items "display_list" which contains products, these products have a field called "pro price" in them which is the price of the product in the list.

If I have a display list with 2 apples and a banana, for example, I want to work out the aggregate price of the 2 apples and banana, how would I go about doing this?

I have currently tried

```
total = sum([(pro.proprice for pro in display_list)])
```

but this isn't working, would anyone be able to lend a hand?
Thanks in advance

Comment: remove the brackets.

Comment: even you can use pandas `df.groupby(['display_list']).sum()` if do in panads

Comment: Can you post a copy of your list setup

Answer (score 4):

You write *brackets* in the list comprehension, as a result you make a list containing *one* element: a generator. You can not take the sum of one generator.

You can do two things: either pass a generator to `sum(..)`, or you can first generate a list and pass it to the `sum(..)`, so:

```
total = sum([pro.proprice for pro in display_list])
```

or:

```
total = sum(pro.proprice for pro in display_list)
```

That being said, if `display_list` is a `QuerySet`, you can use aggregation:

```
# if display_list is a QuerySet
from django.db.models import Sum

total = display_list.aggregate(total=Sum('proprice'))['total']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
`total = sum([pro.proprice for pro in display_list])`